# equality for the spectral radius and operator norm in $B(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

small question!

It can be proved that $\rho(A)=\|A\|$ if and only if $\|A^n\|=\|A\|^n$, now literature says that for normal operators or for $B(X)$ (the set of lineal and bounded operators in $X$ a Banach space) the equality holds.

It is clear that for $B(X)$, $\|T^n\| \leq \|T\|^n$, the thing is that for the converse it's where i'm having difficulties and for the normal operator can't figure it out either.

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you find the statement that $\rho (A)=\|A\|$ iff $\|A^{n}\|=\|A\|^{n}$ for all $n$?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy, Joseph Muscat- Funtional Analysis Example 13.13 (2).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean $\|A^n\| = \|A\|^n$ in $B(X)$, that's not true.  For example, in a two-dimensional Banach space let $A$ be the operator corresponding to the matrix $\pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$.  Then $A^2 = 0$ so $\|A^2\| < \|A\|^2$.

EDIT: Note also that $\rho(A) = 0 < \|A\|$.

For normal operators, use the Spectral Theorem.

Comment: is there a Spectral Theorem for arbitrary normal operators on a Banach space?

Comment: Oh sure, you're right! So the equality $\rho(A)=||A||$ holds in $B(X)$ but the proof is different?

Comment: @MartinArgerami Maybe, depending on how you define "normal operator" on a Banach space.  You might look at [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02843901)

Comment: @LilianHernández No, so the equality does **not** hold in $B(X)$.

Comment: Oh then I'm confused, usually in books it is common to find the invertibility theorem as if $||A||<1$ then $Id-A$ is invertible. Then how the radius is related to this result? @RobertIsrael

Comment: Yes, you are confused.  $\rho(A) \le \|A\| < 1$ implies $1 \notin \sigma(A)$, i.e. $Id - A$ is invertible.  You don't need $\rho(A) = \|A\|$ for that.